# Error when I Click on Catalog -> Manage Categories in Magento Admin Panel

Tags: magento

I am getting following error when I click on Catalog -> Manage Categories in Magento Admin Panel

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

```
Error log record number: 564175648292
```

I saw in log report for message...

Source model "eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean" not found for attribute "is_active".

following is the content of the file:

```html
> a:5:{i:0;s:86:"Source model "eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean" not found for attribute "is_active"";i:1;s:4185:"#0 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "e...')
#1 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
#3 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#8 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
#9 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
#10 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#11 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(93): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
#12 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
#13 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#14 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#15 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#16 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#17 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#18 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#19 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#20 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#21 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#22 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
#23 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#24 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#25 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#26 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#27 /home/eletrofu/public_html/v3/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#28 {main}";s:3:"url";s:83:"/v3/index.php/adminapp/catalog_category/index/key/4b27c04f529065b915b8fd03418e1fda/";s:11:"script_name";s:13:"/v3/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin"
```

Comment: Was the attribute is_active installed by an extension?   If there is an attribute that has a custom source model and that attribute is loaded in the collection.  Magento will look for that source model, won't be able to find it and throw an exception.    When did this start happening? Now, this can also be caused if an attribute source model was removed properly but cache and indexing weren't refreshed as Miad stated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

flush the magento cache and reindex everything . It's probably some code loading problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Catalog > Manage attributes` section in backend and than search for `is_active` attribute or attribute code present or not. if it is present than go for catalog > Manage attributes sets , select the attribute set you are using and drag `is_Active` attribute to unassigned attributes section.